# How to add colors scaled according to allele frequenciensies in waterfall plot of GenVisR?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I want to visualize my genomic data by using waterfall plot function of GenVisR package of R.

I can assign different colors to different mutation types for example nonsense mutations are colored red but I want them to be scaled according to variant allele frequencies.

For example if the mutation is nonsense and had a VAF of 0.8, I want it to be darker compared to another nonsense mutation with VAF of 0.2.

MY CODE:

```
library(GenVisR)


my_data <- data.frame(sample = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3"),gene = c("A", "A", "C"), variant_class = c("NONSENSE", "NONSENSE", "MISSENSE"),amino.acid.change = c("p.C3T", "p.A5D", "p.K2O"),VAF = c(0.9, 0.2, 0.6))

mutation_colours <- c("NONSENSE"='red', "MISSENSE"='green')

sample_order <- c("Sample1", "Sample2", "T3")

mutation_hierarchy <- c("NONSENSE","MISSENSE")


waterfall(my_data, fileType = "Custom", variant_class_order=mutation_hierarchy, mainPalette=mutation_colours, 
          mainLabelSize = 3,mainXlabel= TRUE,sampOrder=sample_order)
```

Comment: One approach would be to use colours corresponding to the muation types, and set the alpha (transparency) with the VAF.